# Get JSON data and convert it into a class in c#

Tags: c#, json

Hi i would like to convert some json data into an instance of a c# class :

for example if i have this json code :

```
"product": [                            
  { 
    "CarBrand": [ 
        "HippoCars", 
        "CondorTrucks", 
        "CheetahMotors"                  
    ], 
    "CarCategory": [ 
        "truck", 
        "car", 
        "MotorBike"
```

And the class :

```
   public class Catalogue
{
    public List<Product> product { get; set; }
 public List<string> CarBrand { get; set; }
    public List<string> CarCategory { get; set; }
}
```

How can I  convert the  JSON data into the c# class?

Comment: [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) is a good choice. Try it out.

Comment: Your JSON is not compatible with that class. The JSON object contains a `product`, not two lists. The `product` contains the lists. So you'll at least need to build one more class. Also, you must use double-quotes to have valid JSON, not single-quotes. (And you're missing a closing square bracket and have some other formatting issues as well).

Comment: Look at using `DataContractJsonSerializer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your JSON is not correct. This is correct:

```
{ 
"product": [                              <--- double quotes
  { 
    "CarBrand": [ 
        "HippoCars", 
        "CondorTrucks", 
        "CheetahMotors"                   <---- no trailing comma
    ], 
    "CarCategory": [ 
        "truck", 
        "car", 
        "MotorBike"
    ]
  }                                       <----- closing object curly brackets
]                                         <----- closing array square brackets
}                                         <----- final }
```

Then you need to have two classes, not one:

```
public class Catalogue
{
    public List<Product> product { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public List<string> CarBrand { get; set; }
    public List<string> CarCategory { get; set; }
}
```

Only than you can use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) as other suggested or

```
Catalogue catalogue = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Catalogue>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try using

```
var mydata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Catalogue>(jsonString);
```